# how to use getServingUrl for getting blobstore image url using the Appengine ImageService?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am able to serve the image using blobl key -
 `res.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKeys.get(0).getKeyString());`

But in the [Appengine Blobstore docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) it is mentioned like this -

*Note: If you are serving images, a more efficient and potentially less-expensive method is to use getServingUrl() using the App Engine Images API rather than blobstoreService.serve(). The getServingUrl method lets you serve the image directly, without having to go through your App Engine instances.*

I want to know how can do that here is my snippet code -

```
Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("myFile");

if (blobKeys == null || blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
    res.sendRedirect("/");
} else {
    res.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKeys.get(0).getKeyString());
}
```

[imageService docs here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService#getServingUrl-com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions-)
[image: Get Serving Url Doc]

Comment: use PHP instead of java you can refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646849/how-can-we-use-firebase-image-file-and-resize-them-using-get-serving-url/37673504#37673504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (blobKeys == null || blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
         res.sendRedirect("/");
     } else {
         //todo add the user
         ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
         ServingUrlOptions servingOptions = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKeys.get(0));
         String servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(servingOptions);
         res.sendRedirect(servingUrl);
        // res.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKeys.get(0).getKeyString());
     }
```